# CakePHP HTML email rendered as view

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to send an html email but it is rendered as a view and then everything stops.

My code is very basic

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('enquiry', 'default')
      ->emailFormat('html')
      ->to('mymail@mail.com')
      ->from('notme@mail.com');
$Email->send()
```

Text email works fine.

I followed the trail code through the cake codebase down to _render in CakeView. I think that something is preventing the rendered email template to be returned and echoes it to the screen instead.

I checked output_buffering in php.ini, it's set to 4096.

This is an inherited project, was working on the original server but not on mine.

Do you have any ideas about what else to look for? Thanks

Comment: what is the action function looks like

Comment: It seems that the previous developers left an exit instruction in the html template which I didn't spotted earlier

Answer (score 2):

Check Path of templete file app\View\Emails\html\enquiry.ctp

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email'); 
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config('default');
$email->from(array('notme@mail.com' => 'Not Me'));
$email->to('mymail@mail.com');
$email->subject('Test mail');
$email->viewVars($message);
$email->template('enquiry', 'default');
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->send();
```

Hope this will help!